# Dynamic css registered property

Tags: html, css

If I make use of css registered property

How can I pass on dynamic values?

For example, in the following example, how can I pass on `---numValue=35` to `to{--num:}`

```css
@property --num {
    syntax: "<integer>";
    initial-value: 0;
    inherits: false;
}

div {
    counter-reset: num var(--num);
    animation: counter 3s linear 1 forwards;
}

div::before {
    content: counter(num);
}

@keyframes counter {
    to {
        --num: 60
    }
}
```

```html
<div style="--numValue:35"></div>
```

Comment: you want to change 60 to 35? or 35 as start number?

Comment: Yes, 60 to 35. But not by hardcoding. I was wondering if there is a way to pass on that value dynamically? Cause that number will get calculated and get stored in the `div` and I want to pass on that number dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding `from` property in transition with the value that you passed dynamically, the number can start from the given one

```
@keyframes counter {
        from {
            --num: var(--numValue)
        }
        to {
            --num: 60
        }
    }
```

```css
@property --num {
    syntax: "<integer>";
    initial-value: 0;
    inherits: false;
}

div {
    counter-reset: num var(--num);
    animation: counter 3s linear 1 forwards;
}

div::before {
    content: counter(num);
}

@keyframes counter {
    from {
        --num: var(--numValue)
    }
    to {
        --num: 60
    }
}
```

```html
<div style="--numValue:35"></div>
```